# How to clone all element under a div with unique id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code I tried so far.

```
  <div class="form-group row insert" id="form-group-insert0">
   <label style="text- transform: capitalize" for="column" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Column</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
      <select class="form-control" name="id (int)" id="id0"></select>
      <select class="form-control" name="name (varchar)" id="name0"></select>
      <select class="form-control" name="primary_details_schema (text)" id="primary_details_schema0">      
      </select>
      &nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary insert_more" value="Insert more" id="insert_more">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to clone the above div each time when click on Insert more button with unique id.
Also clone div have a Remove button instead of Insert button.
It will be like below:

```
 <div class="form-group row insert" id="form-group-insert1">
   <label style="text- transform: capitalize" for="column" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Column</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
      <select class="form-control" name="id (int)" id="id1"></select>
      <select class="form-control" name="name (varchar)" id="name1"></select>
      <select class="form-control" name="primary_details_schema (text)" id="primary_details_schema1">      
      </select>
      &nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove" value="Remove" id="remove">
   </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code:

```
$sharerCount=1;         
$(document).on('click', ".insert_more", function (){
    $('#form-group-insert0').clone().attr('id', 'form-group-insert_' + $sharerCount).insertAfter('.insert:last').find("*[id]").attr('id', 'input_' + $sharerCount).val("").clone().end();
      $sharerCount += 1;

});
```

Comment: You clone, update the id of the clone and insert it *then* find *all* the IDs and change them all to the *same* id.  (then an extraneous clone+end which aren't used/needed) - first: is that your intention (change *all* the Ids)?  Second: What's the actual issue?

Comment: Yes.. I want to change all the id. So that I can take all the value that is dynamically created. The issue is I want to develop a query builder where user can add value and after that the query builder take all the values from the field and make a sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the id's because really, they step on each others toes and add unnecessary complexity. For example, you would create 5 form-groups and then delete the 3rd one. Do you have to then cycle through and adjust everyone else's id? The id's are essentially indexes and that is easy enough to get dynamically. The best way to approach dynamically created elements and their properties are through relative paths. If there were actual IDs involved, that would be a consideration, but for something like this...

```js
$(document).on('click', ".remove_clone", function() {
  $(this).closest('[data-cloned-insert]').remove()
})
$(document).on('click', ".insert_more", function() {
  let clone = $('[data-master-insert]').clone();
  clone.insertAfter($('.form-group:last')).removeAttr('data-master-insert').attr('data-cloned-insert', '').find('input[type=button]').val('Remove').removeClass('insert_more').addClass('remove_clone')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row insert" data-master-insert>
  <label style="text- transform: capitalize" for="column" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Column</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <select class="form-control" name="id (int)"></select>
    <select class="form-control" name="name (varchar)"></select>
    <select class="form-control" name="primary_details_schema">
    </select>
    &nbsp;<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary insert_more" value="Insert more">
  </div>
</div>
```